# Change layout products in orocommerce

Tags: orocommerce

I have a problem with storefont customization,I created custom bundle [create bundle](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/extension/create-bundle/#index-0) and my firs theme [create custom theme](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/quick-start/#create-a-theme),my website run in locahost enviroment dev,I changed scss in file embedded-products-config.scss:

```
$embedded-products-item-count-desktop: 4 !default;
```

to

```
$embedded-products-item-count-desktop: 6 !default;
```

but when I run css not overide when loading it shows 6 products about 2 seconds and return 4 products immediately.

[image: loading 6 products]

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved this but I would recommend updating the featured product record limit in the back office.

Reports & Segments > Manage Segments > Click Featured Products > Edit > Update  Records Limit to 4.

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0RTK.png)